# Sending emails for SharePoint 2010 using VB

Tags: email, sharepoint-2010

I cannot seem to send emails from visual basic in SharePoint 2010. I am using the code below to generate and send emails but it only works when sending to emails hosted on the server on which the code is running. I want to send to be able to send to any email address - how can I do this?

```
'Test If Email Is Current
If SPUtility.IsEmailServerSet(workflowProperties.Web) = True Then
     'Set Headers
     Dim Headers As New System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary
     Headers.Add("To", "administration@emailaddress.co.uk)
     Headers.Add("From", "sender@emailaddress.co.uk")
     Headers.Add("Subject", "Message Subject")
     Headers.Add("content-type", "text/html")
     'Send Email
     Dim Emailsent As Boolean
     Emailsent = SPUtility.SendEmail(workflowProperties.Web, Headers, "Message Body")
End If
```

Comment: What type (Exchange, IIS SMTP, etc.) of email server do you have configured as the outgoing mail server?

Comment: The outgoing mail server is SMTP - the settings are accessible through the SharePoint Central Administration consol - SMTP is the only option.

Comment: What do you mean by "emails hosted on the server"? Emails which belong to users from SharePoint? If yes then it is not an issue of SharePoint. You need to configure SMTP server itself to be able to send messages on any email.

Comment: I am working on one server which is hosting the SharePoint 2010 program. The company emails are hosted on that server. The 'users' have access to SharePoint and also an email address. Using outlook from client PC's the emails can send to any address. When I send emails from the SharePoint automatically only emails that are hosted on the server work - these are also email addresses of SharePoint users. The SharePoint administration console email sending address is set to CompanyWebAdmin@CompanyName.co.uk - this is the default setting and I have not changed it - should I do something to this?

Comment: SMTP is a protocol implemented by most mail servers. I was asking what type of server you're using because it might be a security/relay setting that needs to be configured. If we know what email server you are using, we might be able to give you info on config settings. Event though it might be a question better suited for http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com